# put request mongoose findOneAndUpdate does not work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

i need to know why my put request does not work, i am using postman to watch the result and i get a "cannot put to movieID", the movie id exist

**my put code is like this**

```
router.put('/movies:id',function(req,res){
Movie.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id,{title:"the gift4",releaseYear:"2012",director:"stefan",genre:"horror"},function(err){
    if(err){
        return res.send(err);
    }
    console.log({message:"movie updated"});
});
});
```

i had a solution where i past the req.body as the second parameter and then on postman i defined the req.body dunno if that was the problem on that case, but this solution does not work either, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you change the findOneAndUpdate first parameter to { _id : req.params.id }  and try ?

Comment: i will post the answer, when a guy search top down happens that the error is to simple to be real :D, thanks anyways

Answer (score 2):

Well i discovered my own issue, the thing is that i was routing to /movies:id i could not get the req.params.id, because i missed a slash, it should be /movies/:id 
**so the right answer is here:**

```
router.put('/movies/:id',function(req,res){
     Movie.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id,{title:"the gift4",releaseYear:"2012",director:"stefan",genre:"horror"},function(err){
         if(err){
            return res.send(err);
         }
       console.log({message:"movie updated"});
    });
});
```